# Plot lines with different x asixs in the same graph

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have two dataframe df and df2. They have dates as index and share prices as col.
The dates df is 1/12/18-now
dates of df2 is now +1 day, now +2 day,now +3 day
I want to plot them out in the same graph. I also want interval of x asix to be 10 days.This is my attempt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax1 = plt.subplots(111)
ax2 = plt.subplots(112)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)

y1=df
y2=df2
X2=pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
x=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x2, y2, 'b-')

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

But the get key error msg as

```
---> 17     ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
     18     ax2.plot(x2, y2, 'b-')
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'plot'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The para for subplots is that number of subplots, which you want to create. Hence give one, which seems to want you need. If you want to plot both of them in the same graph, use the same axis.

```
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(1)

y1=df
y2=df2
X2=pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
x=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax1.plot(x2, y2, 'b-')
```

Answer (score 1):

You called a similarly named, but wrong method. Must be:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = plt.subplot(112)
```

`plt.subplots(111)` creates 111 subplots. `plt.subplot(111)` creates one subplot in the position `111`.

Comment: it returns key error                                        
      7     import matplotlib.dates as mdates
      8     ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
----> 9     ax2 = plt.subplot(112)
     10 
     11     plt.xticks(rotation=70)
.........
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 1, not 2

Comment: Yes it is a different error with error value being "ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 1, not 2 " It seems that it is not happy with "ax2 = plt.subplot(112) "

Comment: The error tells you that you are trying to create a second subplot on a 1 by 1 grid .- which is impossible. Now I'm not sure what the ultimate goal here is, but at least this answer would need to take `211` and `212` as parameters.